# How to fix 'Cannot set property 'ref' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So what I try to do is very simple: just receive data from Cloud Firestore.

I have following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

export default class newsFeed extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('keys')
}

 async load(id) {
  const doc = await this.ref.doc(id).get()
  if (doc.exists) {
    return doc.data()
  }
 }
}
```

I receive an error: 'Cannot set property 'ref' of undefined'.

How can I fix it and what's the problem?

Learned it from this tutorial: https://medium.com/react-native-training/firebase-sdk-with-firestore-for-react-native-apps-in-2018-aa89a67d6934

Comment: Use lamba function ( => ). Normal functions do not inherit *this* context.

Answer (score 0):

Usually arrow functions help.

```
 load = async (id) => { //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the class without creating an instance. You should do something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

class NewsFeed extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('keys')
}

 async load(id) {
  const doc = await this.ref.doc(id).get()
  if (doc.exists) {
    return doc.data()
  }
 }
}

export default newsFeed = new NewsFeed();
```

Hope that helps :)